# CSS filed requested twice. MVC

Tags: html, css

i have added my css files that are bundled like this

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/vendors/css")

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/fonts/fonts.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and in firefox , chrome i see these 3 files requested twice

first request with header

```
Accept  text/css,*/*;q=0.1
```

Second request with header

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

this is same for all 3 files and i don't know who requested second file with different headers

can some one help me how can i fix it.?? any help will be appreciated

Comment: does it matter? just remove your 3 lines and it should work fine no?

Comment: yes it does matter as second request doesn't made by application explicitly and i wanted to know how its been made and also second request doesn't get cached